# Manage Club Finances Digitally

Tags: non-profit, student

I am an officer of an unofficial club made up of (mostly) college students. Currently we keep all of our money in cash and manage dues face-to-face and payments (for trips, etc.) on a case-by-case basis. This usually end up being a deposit to one person's bank account so they can pay with a card.

As may be plain, this "solution" is not optimal. We are not able to become an officially recognized club as our activities (Scuba diving) are not "authorized." We've looked into registering as a nonprofit, but it looks like we'd need one individual to register as the CEO (or equivalent, can't remember the exact term used). We rotate our officers yearly, so this won't work. We've also thought about using venmo/PayPal without a bank account (and just eating the fees), but imagine this could get us into some murky waters tax wise.

Is there a good option for us to manage our money in a better way? Open to any and all suggestions... Thanks.

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/other-non-profits/social-clubs

Comment: You might want to post this question on the popular scuba forum (you can find it easily enough) and find out what other clubs do -- there's a solution for you. Insurance is another issue as you become more organized.